# $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\log (n\sin \frac{1}{n}),$ converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Although I am not sure how to prove it, I guess the series is more likely to converge, for we have
$$\log (n\sin \frac{1}{n}) = \log 1 + o(1) = o(1).$$

Is there a neat proof for the convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you advance

> $$ n\sin(1/n) \sim n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{3!\,n^3}\right) = 1-\frac{1}{3!\,n^2} $$

and then

> $$\ln\left( 1-\frac{1}{3!\,n^2} \right) \sim \frac{1}{3!\,n^2}$$

Comment: Taylor's result? Yeah. Yes, using expansion also on $\log(\cdot )$ seems to be able to get things done.

Comment: @Chou: Yes you see how now.